# JSONP request timeout in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, jsonp

I am sending a jsonp request to localhost for getting a json data. But I am getting request timeout. I am not able to figure out the cause of timeout.
Can anybody help me? Below is the function

```
init: function() {
    var me = this;
    //making the jsonp request to fetch data
    console.log("init start");
    Ext.data.JsonP.request({
      url : 'http://localhost/TwitterApp/resources/json/Data.json',
      success: function(response){
      //populating the data in the store
        //console.log("aaaa" + response);
        var store = me.getDataStore();
        store.loadData(response);
        //console.log("on Init" + store);
        me.getStatistics().renderColumnCharts(store);
      },
      failure: function(response){
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
},
```

This is Data.json file. and it is at the same location as specified in the code

```
[
{
    Hashtag: "Hello",
    Value: 1
},
{
    Hashtag: "Hi",
    Value: 4
},
{
    Hashtag: "Obama",
    Value: 61
},
{
    Hashtag: "Close",
    Value: 551
},
{
    Hashtag: "MOD",
    Value: 15
},
{
    Hashtag: "winter",
    Value: 51
},
{
    Hashtag: "chadar",
    Value: 71
},
{
    Hashtag: "bottle",
    Value: 17
},
{
    Hashtag: "jaiHo",
    Value: 154
},
{
    Hashtag: "Madhur",
    Value: 144
},
{
    Hashtag: "Plank",
    Value: 142
},
{
    Hashtag: "Gft",
    Value: 1
}
]
```

I tried inspecting network request. In showed json content form the file in the response body. But still it is going to failure function and giving timeout.
Attached hereby is the screenshot
[image: Response screen shot]

Comment: Are you sure `http://localhost/TwitterApp/resources/json/Data.json` exists? Can we see what it ouputs?

Comment: @A1rPun yes. This file does exist. Checkout above. The output which I am getting is, it is going in the failure function where I am outputting response. I am getting "timeout" as output on console.

Comment: Is the timeout occuring around 30 seconds?  If so, it may be related to the jsonp timeout limit.  I tried mocking up the code in [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2dc) and did not receive the same error.

Comment: @weeksdev I tried increasing the timeout time, but I am still getting timeout error only.

Answer (score 2):

Your response doesn't look like jsonp. The point of jsonp is that it's executed as javascript, and the response had to wrap the data in a function call. Try sending this response:

```
callback([{Hashtag: "Hello",Value: 1}, ... ]);
```

I'm not sure how extjs handles jsonp requests. Usually, the name of the callback function is configurable, and the js framework handles this for you. Maybe you need to add `?callback=?` to your url, or specify a callback name in your ext2 jsonp request. Maybe ext2 already passes a callback parameter to your server and you ignore it.